# How to map a dynamic type to a dictionary for a JSON

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net, idictionary

I want to take a JSON string and map it to a dictionary so I can have access to its key-value pairs and then check the values after. I keep getting an error:

> Unable to cast object of type `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject` to type `System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary [System.String,System.Object].string`

```cs
IDictionary<string, object> dict = (IDictionary<string, object>)source;
```

`source` is from the JSON string.

Comment: Can you attach the JSON for reference? Thanks.

Comment: {
"valid": true,
  "username": "james.green@email.com",
   "departments": [
    "marketing",
     "software"
   ]
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of explicit casting from `JObject` to `Dictionary`, use [`JObject.ToObject<T>()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToObject__1.htm).

```cs
IDictionary<string, object> dict = source.ToObject<Dictionary<string, object>>();
```